# Expressing a function in terms of sinc(t)

Tags: signal-processing

Given the function:

$S(t) = sin(t/\Delta)/t$

How can one express this function in terms of:

$S(t) = sin(t)/t$

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried so far? Telling us well help us better answer your question.

Comment: So far, I've tried expanding each side into their complex exponential forms, then isolating t on both sides and trying to solve the equation. That's not been getting me anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion: since they're different functions, give them different names. Say

$$
U(t) = \sin(t/\Delta) / t \\
S(t) = \sin(t)/t
$$
Now, using substitution, try writing out and simplifying 
$$
U(\Delta s)
$$
and comparing that to 
$$
S(s).
$$

Comment: Thanks for your help. This gives me $U(\Delta*s)=\Delta*S(s)$, but I can't seem to find a value of $s$ that results in relating $sin(t/\Delta)$ to $sin(t)$. Maybe I'm missing something obvious, or not aiming for the right thing here.

Comment: Essentially everything I'm writing down simplifies to $sin(t) = sin(t)$ or $sin(t/\Delta)=sin(t/\Delta)$.

Comment: You got $U(\Delta s) = \Delta S(s)$. If you substitute $t = \Delta s$, i.e., $s = t/\Delta$, you get $U(t) = \Delta S(t/\Delta)$. And that's about all you can hope for. It expresses $U(t)$ in terms of the function $S$...just not $S(t)$. There's no simple formula, in general, for relating $\sin(ct)$ to $\sin(t)$ when $c$ is not an integer.

Comment: Right, so I guess I wasn't looking for a more explicit relation than what is possible. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.